# Using prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest) from GWT presenter widget

Tags: java, gwt, url-parameters, gwtp

I am trying to get a URL parameter from a GWT presenter widget, but I am getting these error messages:

```
The method prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest) of type ViewDiagramPresenter must override or implement a supertype method
The method prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest) is undefined for the type PresenterWidget<ViewDiagramPresenter.MyView>
```

Any ideas? THANK YOU

```
public class ViewDiagramPresenter extends
        PresenterWidget<ViewDiagramPresenter.MyView> {
[...]

@Override
     public void prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest placeRequest) {
       super.prepareFromRequest(placeRequest);
       String actionString = placeRequest.getParameter("action", "view");
    }
[...]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the `PlaceManager` into your PresenterWidget and handle the url in the `onReset()` method.

```
public class ViewDiagramPresenter extends
        PresenterWidget<ViewDiagramPresenter.MyView> {

    protected final PlaceManager placeManager;

    @Inject
    public ViewDiagramPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view, final MyProxy proxy, final PlaceManager placeManager) {
        super(eventBus, view, proxy);
        this.placeManager = placeManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReset() {
        super.onReset();
        PlaceRequest placeRequest = placeManager.getCurrentPlaceRequest();
        String actionString = placeRequest.getParameter("action", "view");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `PresenterWidget` doesn't seem to have a method called `prepareFromRequest()`. Perhaps you mean to extend the `Presenter` class from gwtp?

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way to get the URL parameters from a PresenterWidget?